# Automating deleting lines of code from .java file, script

Tags: java, scripting, ant

As part of code cleanup, and migrating to new test framework, I need to delete constructor which has argument '`String name`' from all the test classes(Almost 1000+ *.java files). 
For example , the part shown in comment need to be deleted.

```
class A extends TestCase{
   //This need to be deleted.
   public A(String name){
      super(name);
   }
   // End of part to be deleted

}
```

Is there any way to automate this using ant script or using java itself?

Comment: Very strange requirement :) I don't think any one has such thing before

Comment: @org.life.java Interesting requirement, I feel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I supposed you can read all the Java files from a directory, and for each Java file, read it into a String, then use regexp to remove the constructor... something like this?

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("class (\\w+) extends TestCase");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(javaSourceCode);

    String className = "";
    if (m.find()) {
        className = m.group(1);
    }

    String out =  javaSourceCode.replaceFirst("public "+className+"\\s*\\(String name\\)\\s*\\n*\\{[\\w\\W]*?\\}", "");

    System.out.println(out);
```

Comment: Difficult to keep the source code formatting same as before. Still found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

It the pattern is tightly constrained, I'd use `sed` or `perl` for a task like this.

But I'd also consider just leaving the redundant constructors alone.  They don't do much harm, especially if they are all in unit tests.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know sed or perl. Also, my client is a perfectionist. So leaving the constructor as such is not possible.